# Remove object item by partial key name

Tags: javascript, object

I have a javascript object that looks like this:

```
{limit: 2, page: 1, filter[description]: 'foo', filter[id]: 1}
```

I need to remove only items related to the filter and keep it that way:

```
{limit: 2, page: 1}
```

What is the most performative way to perform this procedure?

Comment: `filter[description]` is invalid syntax. What is your actual object?

Comment: Did you mean `{limit: 2, page: 1, 'filter[description]': 'foo', 'filter[id]': 1}`? if not, is `filter[...]` meaning other object `filter`s values?

Comment: I implement this https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/v3/features/filtering in backend and I need remove filter when this is extinct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that those are supposed to be quoted keys, you can filter key-value pairs in between calling `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries`.

This version will remove all entries where the key begins `filter[`.  But you can change that easily enough:

```js
const removeFilters = (obj) => Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (obj) 
  .filter(([k, v]) => !k.startsWith('filter[')
))

const input = {limit: 2, page: 1, 'filter[description]': 'foo', 'filter[id]': 1}

console .log (removeFilters (input))
```